# How to get the machine IP address in a “systemd” service file

Tags: bash, systemd, centos-7

I need to get the IP of the machine and use it inside my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redmine server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=redmine
Group=redmine
ip="$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eno16777736 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/redmine/redmine/bin/rails server webrick -e production -b $ip -p 3000

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I execute this command inside the [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) service file and get its result:

```
ip=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eno16777736 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
```

in order to use its result infor `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, sth like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/redmine/redmine/bin/rails server webrick -e production -p 3000 -b $ip
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use [networkd-dispatcher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572302/102385])

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Getting machine hostname with `systemd`.

While I am not deeply familiar with [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) looking over [this tutorial website](https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/) as well as the [official `systemd` man pages](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers), what you seem to be looking for is a “specifier” value:

> Many settings resolve specifiers which may be used to write generic
>   unit files referring to runtime or unit parameters that are replaced
>   when the unit files are loaded.

And the specific specifier I believe would work here is `%H` which is for “Host name” and described as:

> The hostname of the running system at the point in time the unit
>   configuration is loaded.

So checking your example `systemd` script, change your `[Service]` chunk to be this:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=redmine
Group=redmine
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/redmine/redmine/bin/rails server webrick -e production -b %H -p 3000
```

Note the line with the `ip=()` assignment is gone and the `ExecStart` command now uses `%H` instead of `$ip`.

#### An idea for getting an IP address with `systemd`.

That said, it seems that `systemd` only provides a hostname via the `%H` “specifier.” Which is odd if you ask me. So while I have no deep experience with `systemd`, I believe I understand what could be done to achieve the goal of this post.

The key would be to setup an `EnvironmentFile` for `systemd` to read. Read up on how to use [an `EnvironmentFile` over here on this site](http://www.alaux.net/articles/systemd-unit-files-and-environment-variables/).

So let’s say you created a simple Bash script like this; let’s name it `write_ip_to_file.sh` and feel free to change the IP address fetching logic of `ip=$()` to match what works on your setup:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/ {split ($2,A,":"); print A[2]}');
echo IP=$ip > ~/ip.txt;
```

All that would do is output the IP address of `eth0` to a text file named `ip.txt` in your home directory. The format would be something like this:

```
IP=123.456.789.0
```

Got that? Good. Now in your `systemd` script, change your `[Service]` chunk to be something like this; be sure to set `[your username]` to match the username of the directory where `ip.txt` is saved:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=redmine
Group=redmine
EnvironmentFile=/home/[your username]/ip.txt
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/redmine/redmine/bin/rails server webrick -e production -b $IP -p 3000
```

And what that would do is load the config in `ip.txt` and assign `$IP` the value of `123.456.789.0`. I believe that is what you are looking for.

The key factor here is to get `write_ip_to_file.sh` to run on boot or perhaps even by the `systemd` script itself.

#### Another idea for getting an IP address with `systemd`.

But with that said, I have a better idea (if it works): Move that whole `ExecStart` command into the Bash file called `redmine_start.sh` and make sure the system can read and execute it. The contents of `redmine_start.sh` would be as follows; feel free to change the IP address fetching logic of `ip=$()` to match what works on your setup:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/ {split ($2,A,":"); print A[2]}');
/usr/bin/ruby /home/redmine/redmine/bin/rails server webrick -e production -b $IP -p 3000
```

And then change your `[Service]` chunk to be something like this; be sure to set `[your username]` to match the username of the directory where `redmine_start.sh` is saved:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=redmine
Group=redmine
ExecStart=/home/[your username]/redmine_start.sh
```

If you follow the logic, if all of the logic of `ExecStart` is contained in `redmine_start.sh` then you can use that Bash trick to get the IP address, assign it to a variable and then start Redmine there. The `systemd` script would just be managing when/how to start that.

#### Getting machine IP address with `init.d`.

And for the reference of `init.d` users, I use Ubuntu and when I need to grab a current working system IP address in a Bash or an `init.d` startup script I run something like this:

```
ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/ {split ($2,A,":"); print A[2]}')
```

Of course you need to change `/sbin/ifconfig` to match the location of `ifconfig` on your system, and then also change `eth0` to match the network interface you want to get the IP address of.

But once adjusted to match your setup and needs, that successfully gets an interface’s IP address and assigns it to the variable `ip` which can then be accessed as `$ip` in your script.

Comment: This is for a normal script. But my question was how to do it in a sth.service file in order to supply the current IP address of that interface.

Comment: but this is not working, look at the service code in the first post, this is not working..

Comment: btw, this is a service, and when I view the status, it shows that  $ip is not returning any results, and hence the ip is empty and the service fails to start..

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but %H will not work, option -b needs an IP, not a hostname. Ihave been trying to get the specifier for the machine IP, but apparently I can't find it, or don't know how to search for it.

Comment: I've used `/usr/bin/dig +short fullyqualifydomanname.com |head -1` to get an IP for a script

Comment: elekgeek said "Thank you for your effort, but %H will not work, option -b needs an IP, not a hostname." so I took that to mean hostname was availble.  Unless you know the interface the IP is on, its non-trivial to know where the IP in question is located.   In some use case  maybe it would be even be 127.0.0.1 if just being used inside an isolated machine.

Comment: Now this is a good answer (however many iteration it required to reach that state). Single point of reference for all the research I ended up doing and more, too.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this construction will work. Try it:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=redmine
Group=redmine
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "/bin/systemctl set-environment ip=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eno16777736 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/redmine/redmine/bin/rails server webrick -e production -b ${ip} -p 3000
```

Comment: Confirmed working with `systemd 228`

Answer (score 6):

**Use host IP addresses and `EnvironmentFile`**

You can write your host IP addresses into `/etc/network-environment` file using [setup-network-environment](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/setup-network-environment) utility. Then you can run your app following way:

```
[Unit]
Requires=setup-network-environment.service
After=setup-network-environment.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/network-environment
ExecStart=/opt/bin/kubelet --hostname_override=${DEFAULT_IPV4}
```

Source: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `hostname -i` to get your (first) IP address and save it in SystemD's environment. You can access this variable with `${HOST_IP}`.

Documentation:

- `man hostname` for parameters -i and -I
- `man systemctl` for set-environment
- `man systemd.service` for ExecStartPre

Example

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "systemctl set-environment HOST_IP=$(hostname -i)"
```

Comment: `hostname -i` will return a ip list when there are multiple NICs